# How to get all folders paths that contains music (mp3) in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, enumeration

I'm new in Cocoa.I'm trying to scan computer for music folders,within my application. But I have some logic for it.
What I need to start scaning from /Users , for example if I have /Users/music/anotherMusic and /Users/music/music2/music3  , I need to be able to get only the top for that folders that contains music (/Users/music ). And also need to continue iterate in subfolders to have a count of music files in the root folder (/Users/music). And so on with the same logic continue scanning whole computer.And results should be displayed in table, for example **RESULTS** should be like this

**- -/Users/myComputer/iTunes - 77 folders, 500 music files**

**- /Users/myComputer/Documents/Music -15 music folders,400 music files**

**- /Users/myComputer/Downloads/Media -20 music folders, 325 music

   files    (count of all subdirectories with music)**

How I can do it? What I did ,it is in the code below. But it's going deep all the way down, and give me each path that contains .mp3 music, but I need logic as mentioned above.

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

       NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [manager enumeratorAtPath:@"/Users/"];                  
        NSString * file;
      while((file=[direnum nextObject]))
      {
          NSString * FullPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@",file];

          if ([file hasSuffix:@".mp3"])
        { 
          ///gives a music file path that contains mp3, or I can cut last part, and get the folder path. But no logic as should be.
        }
     }
```

Any ideas, or help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong. You want to get the number of mp3 in your folder, but while a folder only contains folders and mp3 files, the mp3-count is for its parent folder (and if the parent itself only contains folders and mp3s, it counts for its grand-parent, etc.) right ?

[manager enumeratorAtPath] is quite useful, but in this case it will certainly require you to maintain a stack to keep track of your browsed files.

Recursion is bliss, here.

```
- (BOOL)isMp3File:(NSString*)file
{
    return [file hasSuffix:@".mp3"];
}

- (BOOL)isHiddenFile:(NSString*)file
{
    return [file hasPrefix:@"."];
}

- (void)parseForMp3:(NSMutableDictionary*)dic
             inPath:(NSString*)currentPath
          forFolder:(NSString*)folder
{
    BOOL comboBreak = false;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError* error;
    NSArray* files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:currentPath error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        //throw error or anything
    }
    for (NSString *file in files)
    {
        BOOL isDirectory = false;
        NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", currentPath, file];
        [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDirectory];
        comboBreak = comboBreak || (!isDirectory &&
                                    ![self isMp3File:file] &&
                                    ![self isHiddenFile:file]);
        if (comboBreak)
            break;
    }
    for (NSString *file in files)
    {
        BOOL isDirectory = false;
        NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", currentPath, file];
        [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDirectory];
        if (isDirectory)
        {
            if (!comboBreak)
            {
                [self parseForMp3:dic inPath:fullPath forFolder:folder];
            }
            else
            {
                [self parseForMp3:dic inPath:fullPath forFolder:fullPath];
            }
        }
        else if ([self isMp3File:file])
        {
            NSNumber *oldValue = [dic valueForKey:folder];
            oldValue = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[oldValue unsignedIntegerValue] + 1];
            [dic setValue:oldValue forKey:folder];
        }
    }
}


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [self parseForMp3:dic inPath:@"/Users/panosbaroudjian" forFolder:@"/Users/panosbaroudjian"];
    NSLog(@"%@", dic);
}
```

Comment: Thanks It works great and very fast! But there is one problem I can't figure out. It is scanning in alphabetical order, and if you have folder /Users/music/music2/music3  it works fine it displayss /Users/music . But if you have  /Users/music  and Music songs that start with letter 'A' or whatever is bigger 'm', the results will be /Users/music  and /Users/music/music2 , but it should be only the parent directory that contains music, or subfolders of music. How I can fix it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Indeed there's a little mistake. You have to check your file list once before browsing in to check for the comboBreak boolean. I'll edit that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Panos. I tried after your editing, but still the same issue. See what I got  "/Users/Apple/Desktop/w/a/music" = 16;
    "/Users/Apple/Desktop/w/a/music/d" = 3;
    "/Users/Apple/Desktop/w/a/music/d/aa/a/asdfasdf/untitled folder/a" = 1;
    "/Users/Apple/Desktop/w/aaa" = 1;  But it should be only only "/Users/Apple/Desktop/w"   it works sometimes fine, if alphabetical order is right. I tried to fix it but I coudn't, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't because of .DS_STORE files or anything ? The only way I am able to reproduce your bug is when a folder contains a hidden file (like .DS_STORE) which combo breaks the recursion (and we don't want that, indeed). I will edit the answer to check for hidden files (and ignore them).

Comment: Thanks for helping Panos. The way to reproduce, create folder on desktop for example. Put one Music file , Starting for Example with "R" and two folders that contains music, name one that less "R" in alhabetical order, and one that is more "R" , and put some music in them, and try to run program you will see. Panos are you Armenian?

Comment: I tried to change some things, but still the same issue. It should show only show parent folders that contains music. Panos do you have idea what can I try?

Comment: Just tried your example and I got "/Users/panos/Desktop/Test" = 3; which is the normal result. It doesn't show "/Users/panosbaroudjian/Desktop" = 3 because my Desktop contains a lot of other files/folders which aren't mp3 files, so it is not a music directory. There should not be any alphabetical order issue, because there is not any alphabetical consideration. Did you try with the hidden files update ? And yes, I am Armenian, why :p ?

Comment: It seems you didn't get my issue right. create subfolders in your "/Users/panos/Desktop/Test" folder, and name them differently , and put music files in them, with different alphabetical order. and Run program. and you will see results /Users/panos/Desktop/Test and "Users/panos/Desktop/test/otherFolders   but it should be only /Users/panos/Desktop/Test aand count of them. and the whole system with that logic. thanks. I got that you are Armenian from you name. I'm Armenian too!

Comment: Actually I have "Test/R.mp3" "Test/O/A/3.mp3" and "Test/T/A/1.mp3" :s... give me a more precise example by email (baroudjian.panos@gmail.com) :)!

Comment: Thanks I have sent it by email