# Is it possible to show all songs in ios without showing MPMediaPickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, mpmediapickercontroller

I'm trying to access songs in ios device. From my searches, i found out i need to use MPMediaPickerController. So i'm creating media picker and choosing songs.
Is there a shortcut to get all songs without showing MPMediaPickerController and picking songs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560769/how-to-get-all-folders-paths-that-contains-music-mp3-in-cocoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option would be to use MPMediaQuerry: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008220

But I wouldn't call it "a shortcut"...